# What is the best approach to clustering and modeling a network analysis for a large dataset in risk identification?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, weights, clustering, graph-theory

Need guidance! I want to build a ***risk scoring system*** for merchants. The current existing mitigation plans are:

1. Using the count of hits by the rule engine (i.e., consecutive massive transactions, shared devices, etc.) to determine whether or not that merchant is high-risk.
2. Flag every merchant with attributes common to fraudsters according to the regulatory compliance list (by business type, province, segment, size, etc.)

However, the result is deemed too naive as it only targets a particular fraud problem defined by the generic behaviors or transactions already known as suspicious; therefore, I want to classify all of the merchants as high, medium, or low risk using a more in-depth measurement:

## Semi-supervised learning approach

Data is separated by three categories:

1. **Labeled high risk behaviors** (rule engine risk, compliance risk, reported risk) - known risk
2. **Grouped by attribute cluster** (location, segment, size) - unknown risk
3. **Network relationship** between each merchant (merchants related with other merchants for syndicate indicator, merchants related with customers for collusion indicator) - unknown risk

The issue is that I don't have labeled data to train the weight calculation, so I've been thinking about using unsupervised learning to cluster these merchants. ***What kind of model would be fitting to tackle this issue?*** Or should I just use all the merchants flagged by the rule engine as the supervised data (but then it would be the same as simply using the rule engine)?

Would anomaly detection be useful here? I'm debating whether to just ***group all the merchants with similar behaviors or attributes*** (regardless of whether they are flagged by the rule engine or not) into clusters using K-Nearest Neighbors ***or just isolate the anomaly*** using Isolation Forest (does the data need to be an outlier for it to be indicated as suspicious though? because it's possible that there are a large group of high-risk merchants?

Second, how do I determine the syndicate and collusion? So far, I've only been using ***network analysis*** (NetworkX on Python) for requested or reported users to see users related to them. ***How do I implement this on a larger scale*** (with hundreds of millions of merchants and users)? Wouldn't that confound the betweenness centrality index? I've been reading about Relational Graph Convolutional Network (RGCN), and I wonder if this is a fitting solution to this.

Or is there another more common solution or parameter that I overlooked? Any advice, guidance, or reading materials would be much appreciated. Thank you!

### ADDITIONAL INFO

Feature Engineering (new parameters made for each merchant, 1-11 done, 12-14 in consideration)

**by rule engine/FDS risk (count of each FDS hit per category for merchants) - known risk:**

1. count of Loyalty Abuse (integer)
2. count of Product Loophole (integer)
3. count of Social Engineering (integer)

**by Compliance risk - known risk:**

4. high risk business type (1=low, 2=medium, 3=high)
5. high risk province according to compliance (1=low, 2=medium, 3=high)
6. high risk/common location for fraudster (1=low, 2=medium, 3=high)
7. high risk merchant size (1=low, 2=medium, 3=high)

**by Reported risk - known risk:**

8. merchant with reported msisdn (3=high), merchant related to reported msisdn (2=medium)

**by Attribute cluster - unknown risk:**

9. segment (string)
10. subsegment (string)
11. province (string)

**by Network relationship (each transaction) - unknown risk:**

12. merchants related with other merchants (syndicate indication)
13. merchants related with customers (collusion indication)
14. coordinate (geographical information of source and target)